# Как сверстать (анимация) такое меню?

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, анимация

Здравствуйте.

Имеется задача сделать меню.
Меню будет на одностраничном сайте, а пункты меню будут подгружать контент на страницу, итак:

Меню такого типа:
[image: картинка меню]

Суть такова:
Только при ховере на пункты меню (кружочки) до них должна доезжать линия (она кстати градиент от кружочка до кружочка), линия начинает движение от начального состояния, проходя через кружочек подсвечивает его.

Линия(соединяющая кружочки) так же может уменьшаться, если был выбран 6ой пункт а мы наводим на 3ий

"Линия должна как бы двигаться за мышкой гася или зажигая пункты"
"активный 2ой пункт, а мы наводим на 6ой, то полосочка должна пройтись от 2ого к 6ому, зажигая попутно все кружочки"

Подскажите как такое реализовать...
я попробовал, почему-то слишком много когда для такой, на первый взгляд не сложной задачи

Подскажите алгоритм, или похожую реализацию где...
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

[ссылка на кодепен](http://codepen.io/untca/pen/gPJNPx)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // получаем блок с меню  
  var _root = $('.menu');

  $(".menu__point").hover(
    function() {
      var _this = $(this),
        time = 0,
        _child = _root.children();
      // пнукт, на котоырй навели  
      _this.addClass('on-hover');

      // проходя по всем потомкам, до того на котоырй навели(у него класс on-hover)
      // вешаем класс с задержкой, котоырй увеличивает плавно width
      $.each(_child, function(index, val) {
        if ($(val).hasClass('on-hover')) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(val).addClass('menu__point--red')
          }, time);
          return false; // дошли до пункта, на котоырй довели, дальше навешивать классы не нужно
        } else {
          if ($(val).hasClass('menu__line')) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(val).find('.menu__line--red')
                .addClass('menu__line--red--active')
            }, time);
            time += 300;
          } else {
            // кроме линии, еслт толко кружочек, для него свой класс (хз почему)))
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(val).addClass('menu__point--red')
            }, time);
          }
        }
      });
    },
    function() {
      var _this = $(this),
        time = 0,
        _child = _root.children().toArray().reverse(); // в цикле клас убираем в обратном порядке

      // когда убрали ховер, то проходим по всем детям и убираем класс активности с задержкой
      // опять же косяк, начинаем убирать с полседнего, а надо бы с того у которго класс on-hover (не доделал)
      $.each(_child, function(index, val) {
        $(val).removeClass('on-hover');
        if ($(val).hasClass('menu__line')) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(val).find('.menu__line--red')
              .removeClass('menu__line--red--active')
          }, time);
          time += 300;
        } else {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(val).removeClass('menu__point--red')
          }, time);
        }
      });
    } // лапша
  );
});
```

```css
.menu{
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.menu__point{
    float: left;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu__point.menu__point--red:before{
    width: 100%;
}

.menu__point:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    width: 0%;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .1s linear;
    -o-transition: all .1s linear;
    transition: all .1s linear  ;
}

.menu__line--red{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0%;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .3s linear;
    -o-transition: all .3s linear;
    transition: all .3s linear  ;
}
.menu__line--red--active{
    width: 100%;
}
.menu__line{
    max-width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: #000;
    margin-top: 12px;
    position: relative;
}

.menu__line--first{
    width: 30px;
}






.clearfix {
    display: block;
}

.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    content: ".";
    line-height: 0;
}

/* IE6 */
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}

/* IE7 */
*:first-child + html .clearfix {
    min-height: 1%;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  РАБОТАЕТ УЖАСНО
  ЕСЛИ БЫСТО ВОДИТЬ МЫШКОЙ ТО плохо
  АНИМАЦИЯ ТОЛЬКО LINEAR — тоже плохо
  ХОЧУ ПРОЩЕ

из за setTIMEOUT, тоже каша получается - работает ужасно...
     -->

<div class="menu clearfix">
  <div class="menu__line menu__line--first">
    <span class="menu__line--red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu__point"></div>
  <div class="menu__line">
    <span class="menu__line--red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu__point"></div>
  <div class="menu__line">
    <span class="menu__line--red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu__point"></div>
  <div class="menu__line">
    <span class="menu__line--red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu__point"></div>
  <div class="menu__line">
    <span class="menu__line--red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu__point"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не буду писать как свой ответ, но такая навигация реализована вот здесь в примере: http://codepen.io/tholman/pen/XJjvGO